# Supervising virtualenv django app via supervisor

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip, supervisord

I'm trying to use supervisor in order to manage my django project running gunicorn inside a virtualenv. 
My conf file looks like this:

```
[program:diasporamas]
command=/var/www/django/bin/gunicorn_django
directory=/var/www/django/django_test
process_name=%(program_name)s
user=www-data
autostart=false
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_diasporamas.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=2
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_diasporamas_errors.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=2enter code here
```

The problem is, I need supervisor to launch the command after it has run 'source bin/activate' in my virtualenv. I've been hanging around google trying to find an answer but didn't find anything.

Note: I don't want to use virtualenvwrapper

Any help please?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#activate-script) for the virtualenv activate script says that it only modifies the PATH environment variable, in which case you can do:

```
[program:diasporamas]
command=/var/www/django/bin/gunicorn_django
directory=/var/www/django/django_test
environment=PATH="/var/www/django/bin"
...
```

Since version 3.2 you can use [variable expansion](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables) to preserve the existing PATH too:

```
[program:diasporamas]
command=/var/www/django/bin/gunicorn_django
directory=/var/www/django/django_test
environment=PATH="/var/www/django/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
```

...

Comment: Seems to work :) had read something about envs management but didn't found how to apply it. Thank you, really!

Comment: @serge-s @michał-modzelewski But doesn't this overwrite the `PATH` environment variable? If that's the case, won't that affect the search path for other binaries not found in that directory. For, e.g., in Ubuntu Linux, the `PATH` is `/home/user_name/bin:/home/user_name/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`. If some binary is not found in the overwritten PATH, it should be searched in the directories specified in the original PATH. Is there a way to append to the path in supervisor config (e.g. using string formatting)?

Comment: @LokeshMeher This answer is pretty old. Since then supervisor has added an option to use environment variables in the configuration. I've updated the answer with a version that includes the original PATH.