# Supervisord manage fcgi and django

Tags: django, fastcgi, supervisord

I've managed to set up supervisord with fastcgi on a django project of mine, the problem is that when I make mi program stop, the server keeps running somehow, and my page keeps online.

Here is my supervisord program directive:

```
[program:helloworld]
command=/var/www/django-projects/helloworld/run
```

Here is my "run" script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /var/www/django-projects/helloworld/venv/bin/activate;
/var/www/django-projects/helloworld/manage.py runfcgi \
     daemonize=false \
     host=127.0.0.1 \
     port=8000;
```

All I want is a way to stop/start/restart this django project using supervisord, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't use fcgi I am almost sure that your problem lies with `source /var/www/django-projects/helloworld/venv/bin/activate;`

You shouldn't use `source` inside a supervisor start script, it changes the current shell and there is none with supervisord. Instead just change your path in the supervisord script:

```
directory = /var/www/django-projects/helloworld/
command = /var/www/django-projects/helloworld/manage.py runfcgi \
 daemonize=false \
 host=127.0.0.1 \
 port=8000;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535199/203535) and the [virtualenv documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#activate-script) on using the `activate` script .

Comment: Hi @Density I took your suggestion about virtualenv, however it still doesn't work, would you mind telling me which server do you use and how did you configure it?

Comment: I finally managed to get it running but using gunicorn, although I would really like to use fastcgi.