# Supervisord - environment variables conflict for multiple projects

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, supervisord

I have two sites build on Django, both of them use `gunicorn` managed with `supervisor 2`

**supervisord.conf**:

```
[program:site1]
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/www/virtualenv/site1/bin/:/home/www/site1/"
command=/home/www/virtual/site1/bin/gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:1234
directory=/home/www/site1/
...

[program:site2]
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/www/virtualenv/site2/bin/:/home/www/site2/"
command=/home/www/virtual/site2/bin/gunicorn wsgi:app -b localhost:1235
directory=/home/www/site2/
...
```

With this configuration I noticed that site2 tries to start with settings of site1, and fails because it cant find packages that required for site1, because they are not installed in virtualenv of site2.
I think that it happens because of `PYTHONPATH` mixes between two sites.
How to properly setup both sites to use only own virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Have different configuration files for each site.

Answer (score 0):

I test with simple config as below:-

```
[supervisord]

[program:a]
command = /bin/bash pa.sh
environment = PYTHONPATH=/tmp/a
stdout_logfile = /tmp/a.log

[program:b]
command = /bin/bash pb.sh
environment = PYTHONPATH=/tmp/b
stdout_logfile = /tmp/b.log
```

Both `pa.sh` and `pb.sh` look like this:-

```
while :
    do echo $PYTHONPATH
    sleep 2s
done
```

Then I run supervisord:-

```
supervisord -c sp.cfg -n
2013-09-25 00:43:12,942 INFO supervisord started with pid 15362
2013-09-25 00:43:13,945 INFO spawned: 'a' with pid 15365
2013-09-25 00:43:13,948 INFO spawned: 'b' with pid 15366
2013-09-25 00:43:14,967 INFO success: a entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2013-09-25 00:43:14,968 INFO success: b entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Check `/tmp/a.log` and `/tmp/b.log`:-

```
cat /tmp/a.log 
/tmp/a
/tmp/a
/tmp/a
/tmp/a

cat /tmp/b.log 
/tmp/b
/tmp/b
/tmp/b
/tmp/b
```

So both environment being picked up. Supervisord version - 3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv, you just need to alter your `PATH`, not `PYTHONPATH`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535199/107510).