# Can not deploy django using gunicorn and supervisor

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a django project using gunicorn/nginx as webserserver. The project works perfectly fine when I just run this command in virtualevn:

```
(.zenv)randi@server:/srv/myproj$ gunicorn  --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myproj.wsgi:application
```

However, when I add virtualenv activation & the above command to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myproj.conf`:

```
[program:myproj]
directory = /srv/myproj
user = randi
command = source /home/randi/.zenv/bin/activate  &&  gunicorn  --bind 127.0.0.1:8000  myproj.wsgi:application
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true

stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/access.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/error.log
```

after starting the supervisor  `supervisorctl start all` (as root), I get:

```
myproj: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

and `supervisor status` gives:

```
myproj   FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

There is nothing in error logs to help. I have googled in vein and this problem has tripped my for a while. So I appreciate your help to resolve it.

Comment: I think there are other logs files, e.g. the ones written by gunicorn, not supervisord

Comment: Well there is also a `supervisord.log` which contains lots of: `INFO gave up: myproj entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly`

Comment: I am also having the same issue . Did you get any fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `source` is unknown.

Try by running supervisord in the foreground (add this to your conf):

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
```

and start supervisord (if needed with the `-c path-to-.conf` flag and `-n` for no daemon).

I had this error message:

```
2016-07-21 18:54:16,030 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'source'
```

A solution would be to modify the path directly with the `environment` entry, but I couldn't make it work.

```
environment=PATH="/path/to/venv/bin"
```

See [Supervising virtualenv django app via supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532486/supervising-virtualenv-django-app-via-supervisor)